# Why is page scrolled to the top after calling window.scrollTo(...) wiith non zero Y

Tags: javascript, scroll

I am observing strange behavior and I believe I can exclude some common reasons.
I need to implement scroll position restoration on going back in single page app (in Angular).

First, I need to say that for whole time, for debugging purpose, I have something like style="min-height: 8000px !important;" on body, to be sure that there is always enough space and viewport is not shorter then requested scroll.

history.scrollRestoration is set to "manual"

I am simply calling window.scrollTo(0, Y) when user navigates back.
Sometimes it works perfectly, sometimes it's scrolled to top (and scroll event emitted by browser says also scoll to 0) I dind't find clue why it's ok and why not/

Code looks like

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function (e: any): void {
  console.log('window scrolled to ' + window.scrollY);
});

// called with resored Y value
function onNavigateBack(y) {
  console.log("Before " + window.scrollY)
  console.log("Calling scroll to y = " + y)
  window.scrollTo(0, y) 
  console.log("After " + window.scrollY)
}
```

Assume that saved value is y=470, than output is

```
Before ... (there is actual value)
Calling scroll to y = 470
After 470
.... route is initialized there ...
window scrolled to 0
```

Observations

- no other window.scrollTo neither window.scroll is called (verified by mocking it)
- when scrollTo is not called then scroll to top in wrong case is not happening -> invalid scroll to top is consequence of requested scroll
- no other scoll event is triggered
- Chrome and Firefox are consistent, understand works sometimes

The questions is. Any idea what can cause such behavior? Or what can intercept scrolling?
My first concern was that page is simply too short between rendering, but it preserves even with min-height hack.

EDIT: One more observation
Seems that success scroll is linked to small Y (like never fails for y = 200) and failing on big Y (eg Y > 800px). But still, scrolling bellow page range should scroll to the current bottom. This makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping scrollTo call into window.requesteAnimationFrame callback seems to fix the issue. Although I don't have idea why.